# How does default value internally work in Database?

Tags: mysql, database

How does default value internally work in Database?

If I alter a table:

```
alter table foo
add column aws_region varchar(32) default 'us-east-1';
```

Will it update all rows? Or is default value is just a value lookup if value is not present?

Comment: @juergend Look at Bill Karwin's answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "if value is not present"? You are adding a new column, so how can any value be present to begin with? The question would make more sense (and it would have a different answer) if you asked: "what if I add a default value to an EXISTING column"?

Comment: @Barmar: Ah - I did not see that it is a NEW column. I thought it is an existing one.

Comment: @mathguy I think he's asking how it represents it internally -- does every row get a copy of the default value, or is there some flag saying "This column hasn't been filled in, use the default"?

Comment: If that is the question, the answer is definitely NO. But I am not sure if that's the question. The answer is NO because: if a column has a default value, and a row is inserted where that column is included, and is specifically assigned NULL, then the value will still be NULL; the default comes in only if a value is not assigned at all, but it does not override explicit NULL. So, then - the default value is actually written on disk repeatedly, once for each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to test this out. If you add a column to a table that has one or more rows, it sets the new column to the default.

```
mysql> create table foo (id int primary key);

mysql> insert into foo values (123);

mysql> alter table foo
    -> add column aws_region varchar(32) default 'us-east-1';

mysql> select * from foo;
+-----+------------+
| id  | aws_region |
+-----+------------+
| 123 | us-east-1  |
+-----+------------+
```

If you change the definition of the column, existing rows are not changed. The value in each row is set when you create the row, not when you query it.

```
mysql> alter table foo 
    -> modify column aws_region varchar(32) default 'us-west-2';

mysql> select * from foo;
+-----+------------+
| id  | aws_region |
+-----+------------+
| 123 | us-east-1  |
+-----+------------+
```

New rows you insert after the default has been changed use the new default. The old rows still have the old value.

```
mysql> insert into foo (id) values (456);

mysql> select * from foo;
+-----+------------+
| id  | aws_region |
+-----+------------+
| 123 | us-east-1  |
| 456 | us-west-2  |
+-----+------------+
```

This means that the default value is copied into the row at the time the row is inserted. There is only default at a time, so if the row contained a pointer to the default, and then we changed the default, old rows that used the default would appear to change retroactively, as they now point to the new default value.

They don't do that, as I showed above. Old rows still contain the default that was in effect at the time the row was created. The default value was copied into the row.

Comment: If I interpret the question correctly, this may not be a useful answer. He may be asking whether it's implemented by copying the default into every row or using a flag that says to fetch the default from metadata.

Comment: Either implementation produces the same output.

Comment: The way to tell what it's actually doing is by changing the default value, then notice that existing rows that used the default do not change.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks for your answer. But I am still curious about if us-east-1 will be copied to each row internally?

Comment: @VivekGoel, yes, the default is copied into the row. See my last edit above.

Answer (score 0):

The data which alter table before will not change. Es: if is null after alter it is also null